# All subdomains to the same Virtualhost

Tags: apache, subdomain, virtualhost, wildcard-subdomain

I want `example.com` as well as any subdomain e.g. `abc.example.com` to be served by the same application. I cannot know all subdomains beforehand so I need wildcards. My (Django) application can handle requests to all subdomains.

The problem is that requests to `abc.example.com` return "400 Bad Request".

My Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu) configuration starts like this

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        ServerName example.com
        ServerAlias *.example.com
        DocumentRoot /home/user/project
        # ...
</VirtualHost>
```

Note: I have only defined one VirtualHost, which I intended to cover all subdomains. Requests to all paths of `example.com` e.g. `example.com/api/` work.

Subdomain Requests are not logged in the `access.log` file where regular requests land, but in `other_vhosts_access.log`.

```
$ sudo tail -100 /var/log/apache2/other_vhosts_access.log
example.com:80 10.xx.191.xxx - - [15/Feb/2020:13:15:09 +0000] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.0" 400 317 "http://abc.example.com/" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/xxx.xx (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/80.0.xxxx.xxx Safari/xxx.xx"
```